# Add a second Group Input from a different object/mesh with geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to combine two objects in a geometry nodes tree. Adding the first is easy - just add a geometry node modifier to the object. Adding the second, however...

I can add a second *Group Input* into the geometry nodes tree, but I can see no way to link that to the second object. There are no widgets on it, right clicking does nothing. I have tried dragging the second object from the viewport into the geometry nodes, but that fails. I have looked at the attributes for the modifier and can see nothing there.

I feel this should be easy, but even a Google search failed to find anything.

ETA: I have been asked what I want to achieve. I want to make a pile of coal. I want to have one object that is the surface of the pile (say a section of a sphere). Another that is distributed across the surface randomly (a cube, that gets randomly sized and rotated).

Comment: you are asking about a technical question, which is fine - but maybe it would be more efficient, if you ask about your "end goal", so what do you want to achieve/build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The node you are looking for is called `Object Info` in your case.

Within a geometry node tree, the `Group Input` node on the *Geometry* socket always only returns the geometry that contains the current geometry node tree.

To add and edit another geometry, use `Object Info`. This node provides not only the selected object, but also its transformation properties.

---

To solve your task right away:

To be able to position any object on the surface of another object with different size and rotation, first create some points on the surface with `Distribute Points on Faces`.

Then use these points to instantiate the object integrated into this tree with `Object Info`. The node `Random Value` helps you to randomly create different rotations (in this example only on the Z-axis) and scaling.

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 4.0.2+)*</sub>

Comment: Thanks, great answer and useful download